# Python serial.write() stops working after a while

Tags: python, arduino

I've been writing both a Python module and an Arduino program that would enable users to control an arduino board.

To do that, every time I call a function on python, the following happens: (Let me put digitalWrite as an example)

- Python sends a byte corresponding to the action arduino has to make. (e.g. 3 means digitalWrite())
- Python sends bytes corresponding to the arguments. In this case, its just one for the pin to switch and one for the value to write.
- Arduino reads the information, byte by byte, since they are always in the same order, the first one of them tells Arduino how many arguments are to come, so there is never a missmatch.
- Arduino executes the action, then prints to the serial an exit code, 0 by default.
- Python reads that and returns it to the user.

That's it, I don't know if this is the best way of doing it, but it works as a charm, for a while. I tried making a blinking light, turning it on and off every 0.1 s, and so it does for about 10 seconds (sometimes 1s, sometimes it can stay 30s blinking). Then it all stops. I've been searching for the problem but so far I've only found that a blink or two before crashing, Arduino stops sending the exit code through the serial, and then python's serial.write(pin) (which tells arduino which pin to switch) raises a timeout exception.

Comment: You will have to show your code if you want an answer.